# Video element pause while phone call

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I've got an issue with my app and I could reproduce it on this sample: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/

During a phone call, if I open a tab with a video with audio element, the video automatically pause (and can see a pause event on the element)

This does not happen if the video element was loaded and played before the phone call start, or if the video has no audio.

Is this a normal behaviour, and can it be tracked (by an event other than the pause one) ? Is there any way to know there is a phone call ongoing, or any way to restart the video during the phone call (element.play() works, but a pause event immediately happens) ?

To reproduce:

- On a mobile (iOS or Android)
- Start a phone call
- Open https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/
- The video is paused
- If you manually launch element.play(), you can see the frame in the video updating, and then pause again
- The record works correctly

Comment: not clear what the end goal is ... to pause the video when a call comes in?

Comment: Nope, that is the bug, the goal is to understand where does this pause come from, and how to relaunch the video

Comment: so, the bug is that the video pauses when a phone call comes in?

Comment: no, the video pauses only if the call was ongoing before opening the page with the video. If the video is played, then a phone call launched, the video doesn't pause

Comment: Oh, so when starting a video during a phone call you want it to play

Answer (score 1):

what (likely) happens is that the video element (which needs to synchronize audio and video) is waiting for audio data but doesn't get any from the underlying layers when a phone call is active.

A possible workaround would be to change how you display audio and video, each in their own elements with `MediaStream` as `srcObject` that only have the respective audio and video track of the original stream.

Can you file a specification issue on https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/ please? This is a rather interesting case that warrants some discussion.

Comment: I added a new issue here: https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/issues/869

Comment: A colleague of mine told me Google Meet on browser displays a message 'Already in call' if you attempt to reach a conference during a phone call, so there might be a way for the browser to know that ? I also believe the workaround <video> + <audio> elements would work but i'm curious to know if all of this is documented